# Picasso resize into RoundedImageView changes corner radius

Tags: android, android-layout, picasso, android-4.4-kitkat

I am using Picasso to dynamically load some image into my circular view (a `RoundedImageView` which is a popular library) which has corner radius set as half the width of the view (the image may not be square so I'm center cropping):

`Picasso.with(avatarView.getContext()).load(avatarUrl).centerCrop().resize(100, 100).into(avatarView);`

However, 100x100 image doesn't look nice, so I increase it to `200x200` to make it look better (source image is still much larger). However, then my rounded image view's radius is messed up. The corners have less radius, and the border width is thinner even though I set them both in XML and never touch them anywhere again:

```
<com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
    app:riv_corner_radius="40dp"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/avatarView"
    app:riv_border_color="@color/white"
    app:riv_border_width="1dp" />
```

Why is this happening?